# Compiling emacs24

Tags: emacs, compilation, makefile

I'm doing a cross install of Debian Wheezy, and need to compile `emacs24`. The `emacs24` source is from `git://repo.or.cz/emacs.git`.

Things went well up to the `make` command. It requires `makeinfo`, and so I installed `texinfo`, which gives me `makeinfo` version 4.13a.

So I do:

```
$ make -d --warn-undefined-variables
  ...
  Loading emacs-lisp/byte-run (source)...
  Symbol's function definition is void: defun
  Reaping losing child 0x09e2c4c8 PID 11470
  make[1]: *** [bootstrap-emacs] Error 1
  Removing child 0x09e2c4c8 PID 11470 from chain.
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/haines/emacs/src'
  Reaping losing child 0x095453c0 PID 11412
  make: *** [src] Error 2
  Removing child 0x095453c0 PID 11412 from chain.
```

I do not know what this means.

In case my `makeinfo` is too old, I tried:

```
  $ make --without-makeinfo
```

but this not a valid option despite what directions say.

Haines

Comment: This failure probably has nothing to do with texinfo/makeinfo. Cross-compiling emacs may be a bit of a challenge. Try setting CANNOT_DUMP=yes in the environment and do configure and clean build again.

Comment: If you re-read the directions I expect you'll find they say that the `--without-makeinfo` flag is given to `configure`, not to `make`.  However, ArtemB is right; this doesn't have anything to do with `makeinfo`... is there something about the error that makes you think it's a `makeinfo` issue?  I don't see it.  This is something different.  I don't think the `-d` or `--warn-undefined-variables` to `make` are useful or helpful, either (although they won't actually cause failures).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and suggestion. I reentered chroot with the suggested environment: # LANG=C.UTF-8 CANNOT_DUMP=yes chroot /mnt/debinst /bin/bash. Then redid $ ./autogen.sh, ./config, make, but with same result. I probably will have to install emacs24 after I've booted into the new system.